# Dar el número más grande a través de un array

Tags: c#

Quiero realizar un programa que pida 3 números y devuelva el más grande y más pequeño. Lo quiero hacer con arrays y un for para ahorrarme condicionales pero me dice que la variable numbers no ha sido asignada.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TresNombres
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers;
            Console.WriteLine("Insert first number: ");
            numbers[0] = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert second number: ");
            numbers[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert third number: ");
            numbers[2] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: te dice que numbers no fue asignada porque no inicializaste el array, te falta numbers = new int[]; debes agregarle el tamaño a tu array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
namespace TresNombres
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          int[] numbers;
          int mayor, menor;
          numbers = new numbers[3];
          Console.WriteLine("Insert first number: ");
          numbers[0] = (Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("Insert second number: ");
          numbers[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("Insert third number: ");
          numbers[2] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          mayor = numbers[0];
          menor = numbers[0];
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              if(mayor < numbers[i])
              {
                  mayor = numbers[i];
              }else{
                  menor = numbers[i];
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad! Razona el porqué tu código podría llegar a solucionar tu problema, para que si viene otra persona por la misma duda, pueda entender todo sin problema.

Comment: Esta respuesta contiene un error lógico, al asignar el valor `menor` se le está asignando el valor que resulta de la condicional que garantiza que no es el valor máximo, pero eso no necesariamente garantiza que sea el valor mínimo; para obtener el valor mínimo seria  necesario hacer lo siguiente `if(menor >numbers[i]) menor = numbers[i];`

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar Linq para usar sus métodos y saber cual es el número mayor y menor.

```
    using System.Linq;          

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Insert first number: ");
        numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Insert second number: ");
        numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Insert third number: ");
        numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Max());
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Min());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ambas opciones son validas, como dice uno de ellos, tienes que inicializar el arreglo por ejemplo

`int[] numbers = new int[3]; //3 es el tamaño del arreglo que puedes` elegir.